# Using hbase to save data while parsing pages via nutch1.8

Tags: hbase, nutch

I'm using nutch 1.8 to crawl pages,and want to save `parseText` into hbase while parsing. So I wrote a filter ,but when saving `parseText`, I got this error:

> Thread was interrupted while trying to connect to master.

```
static {
        conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    }

public static void creatTable(String tableName, String[] familys) throws Exception {

        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
        if (admin.tableExists(tableName)) {
            System.out.println("table already exists!");
        } else {
            HTableDescriptor tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
            for (int i = 0; i < familys.length; i++) {
                tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(familys[i]));
            }
            admin.createTable(tableDesc);
            System.out.println("create table " + tableName + " ok.");
        }
    }
```

This code runs well on unitTest, but when integrated with nutch the error occurs. Can anyone help?